# Can I use arrow functions instead of normal functions for React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is it possible to also use arrow functions with the new React Hook syntax? what will be the difference and/or could this cause problems?

documentation syntax:

```
function Example() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

arrow function:

```
 const Example = () => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The short answer is: **yes you can**.

Arrow functions and function declarations/expressions are not equivalent. However, if the function you want to replace does not use `this`, `arguments` and is not called with `new`, then you are free to use whatever style you prefer.

Comment: Is it ok to use arrow functions ALL THE TIME ?  Is there any penalty or gotcha in using arrow functions in certain situations ?

Comment: I use arrow functions all the time. There is even eslint plugin that can force people to do that. eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow

Answer (score 21):

The difference between declaring functional component using `function` or `const` would be the same as the difference between `functional expressions` and `functional declaration`

For instance `Function declarations` load before any code is executed while `Function expressions` load only when the interpreter reaches that line of code i.e rendering a functional component created using `function` syntax can be done before it is defined in the code while if its defined using `expression` then it needs to be declared before using

So in short `function declarations` are hoisted whereas `function expressions` are not

**In terms of using both the above syntaxes to create components you can use either as long as you use hoisting into account**

Comment: Is it ok to use arrow functions ALL THE TIME ?  Is there any penalty or gotcha in using arrow functions in certain situations ?

Answer (score 2):

It’s the same. The difference will be the same as the difference between any function vs arrow function (doesn’t have it’s own scope) but for react hooks it’s the same

Answer (score 2):

*TL;DR*: ***YES***

But I definitely offer to use `function expression` towards the `arrow function`, because using both of them for writing components causes to prevent hoisting issues.

```
const MyComponent = ({ someProp }) => (
  <div>
    {someProp}
  </div>
);
```

For using state:

```
const MyComponent = ({ someProp }) => {
  const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div onClick={setShowText}>
      {showText && <span>some text</span>}
      {someProp}
    </div>
  );
};
```